# flask-oauthlib server doesn't play well with requests-oauthlib client

Tags: python, oauth, flask, oauth-2.0

I have a flask-oauthlib server up and running and have been able to authorize/authenticate correctly when I use the client code from [the example](https://github.com/lepture/example-oauth2-server). I realize that not all of my clients will have flask-oauthlib installed, so I've tried to create a client with requests-oauthlib but it fails on my server (even though the "Github example" that requests-oauthlib provides works correctly).

Here is my requests-oauthlib client code:

```
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, session, url_for
from flask.json import jsonify
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

client_id = 'M2GCECELADgqZNke50iShcXRjq0pyO8i72W38l7U'
client_secret = 'ao5wrWp7RrUuKlgTxjmK6D7Z9dsPlI6fZc2WwkTTG4eEvXsN1q'
authorization_base_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/oauth/authorize'
token_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/oauth/token'

@app.route("/")
def demo():
  remote = OAuth2Session(client_id)
  authorization_url, state = remote.authorization_url(authorization_base_url)
  session['oauth_state'] = state
  return redirect(authorization_url)

@app.route("/authorized", methods=["GET"])
def authorized(): # this is where it fails
  remote = OAuth2Session(client_id, state=session['oauth_state'])
  token = remote.fetch_token(token_url, client_secret=client_secret, authorization_response=request.url)
  session['oauth_token'] = token
  return redirect(url_for('.profile'))

@app.route("/profile", methods=["GET"])
def profile():
  remote = OAuth2Session(client_id, token=session['oauth_token'])
  return jsonify(remote.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/me').json())

if __name__ == "__main__":
  os.environ['DEBUG'] = '1'
  app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)
  app.run(host='localhost', port=8000,debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

On the server, here is the token_handler. It currently returns None and I've tried to have it return a dictionary and a json-encoded dictionary, with no luck.

```
@app.route('/oauth/token')
@oauth.token_handler
def access_token():
  return None
```

The rest of my server code is taken straight from [the flask-oauthlib example](https://github.com/lepture/example-oauth2-server/blob/master/app.py)

Why does this work with one oauthlib client but not the other? I'm new to oauthlib so maybe I'm missing something stupid easy?

EDIT: I am using:

```
oauthlib 0.6.1
flask-oauthlib 0.4.3
requests 2.2.1
requests-oauthlib 0.4.0
flask 0.10.1
python 2.7
```

EDIT #2: The request-oauthlib client's logging:

```
Requesting url http://127.0.0.1:5000/oauth/token using method POST.
Supplying headers {u'Accept': u'application/json'} and data {u'code': u'vG7shZebClhAjzmSUQuHoqlXNrPTVr', u'client_secret': u'qdlmQvf5tdSVxFqixeE4wOKxe3awfEbsymCOpjeTIZEaWjbbB5', u'grant_type': u'authorization_code', u'client_id': u'EXewK3X3dU1NiWk7AfNj43jrhpSy8bHQm1mOHC96'}
Passing through key word arguments {'auth': None}.
Prepared fetch token request body grant_type=authorization_code&code=vG7shZebClhAjzmSUQuHoqlXNrPTVr&client_id=EXewK3X3dU1NiWk7AfNj43jrhpSy8bHQm1mOHC96&client_secret=qdlmQvf5tdSVxFqixeE4wOKxe3awfEbsymCOpjeTIZEaWjbbB5
Request to fetch token completed with status 405.
Response headers were CaseInsensitiveDict({'date': 'Tue, 25 Feb 2014 21:19:32 GMT', 'content-length': '178', 'content-type': 'text/html', 'allow': 'HEAD, OPTIONS, GET', 'server': 'Werkzeug/0.9.4 Python/2.7.5+'}) and content <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>
<h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>
<p>The method is not allowed for the requested URL.</p>
.
Invoking 0 token response hooks.
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2014 14:19:32] "GET /authorized?state=qPJnIJctmsTbojT2nTOkgRNwgnU8vF&code=vG7shZebClhAjzmSUQuHoqlXNrPTVr HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
....
....
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

EDIT #3: The server's flask-oauthlib logging:

```
Found redirect_uri None.
Validate client u'EXewK3X3dU1NiWk7AfNj43jrhpSy8bHQm1mOHC96'
Found default redirect uri 'http://localhost:8000/authorized'
Found default scopes ['email']
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2014 14:19:30] "GET /oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=EXewK3X3dU1NiWk7AfNj43jrhpSy8bHQm1mOHC96&state=qPJnIJctmsTbojT2nTOkgRNwgnU8vF HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Fetched credentials from request {'state': u'qPJnIJctmsTbojT2nTOkgRNwgnU8vF', 'redirect_uri': None, 'response_type': u'code', 'client_id': u'EXewK3X3dU1NiWk7AfNj43jrhpSy8bHQm1mOHC96'}.
Found redirect_uri None.
Validate client u'EXewK3X3dU1NiWk7AfNj43jrhpSy8bHQm1mOHC96'
Found default redirect uri 'http://localhost:8000/authorized'
Persist authorization code {u'state': u'qPJnIJctmsTbojT2nTOkgRNwgnU8vF', u'code': u'vG7shZebClhAjzmSUQuHoqlXNrPTVr'} for client u'EXewK3X3dU1NiWk7AfNj43jrhpSy8bHQm1mOHC96'
Authorization successful.
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2014 14:19:32] "POST /oauth/authorize HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2014 14:19:32] "POST /oauth/token HTTP/1.1" 405 -
```

EDIT #4: The server's oauthlib logging:

```
Validating redirection uri None for client EXewK3X3dU1NiWk7AfNj43jrhpSy8bHQm1mOHC96.
Using default redirect_uri http://localhost:8000/authorized.
Validating access to scopes ['email'] for client u'EXewK3X3dU1NiWk7AfNj43jrhpSy8bHQm1mOHC96' (<api.models.Client object at 0x7fb104026e50>).
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2014 14:12:30] "GET /oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=EXewK3X3dU1NiWk7AfNj43jrhpSy8bHQm1mOHC96&state=oHvelCpzosGfJd7ZzCeBvsmRANmipb HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Dispatching response_type code request to <oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.grant_types.authorization_code.AuthorizationCodeGrant object at 0x2db44d0>.
Validating redirection uri None for client EXewK3X3dU1NiWk7AfNj43jrhpSy8bHQm1mOHC96.
Using default redirect_uri http://localhost:8000/authorized.
Validating access to scopes [u'email'] for client u'EXewK3X3dU1NiWk7AfNj43jrhpSy8bHQm1mOHC96' (<api.models.Client object at 0x7fb10403e210>).
Pre resource owner authorization validation ok for <oauthlib.common.Request object at 0x7fb104026210>.
Created authorization code grant {u'state': u'oHvelCpzosGfJd7ZzCeBvsmRANmipb', u'code': u'yAZZwtCd1IyAeBtHEgg4YTnHl46Ddf'} for request <oauthlib.common.Request object at 0x7fb104026210>.
Saving grant {u'state': u'oHvelCpzosGfJd7ZzCeBvsmRANmipb', u'code': u'yAZZwtCd1IyAeBtHEgg4YTnHl46Ddf'} for <oauthlib.common.Request object at 0x7fb104026210>.
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2014 14:12:32] "POST /oauth/authorize HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2014 14:12:32] "POST /oauth/token HTTP/1.1" 405 -
```

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser history and sessions? Sometimes the old tokens, etc can hang around there.

Comment: I did. I even tried it in Firefox and Chrome and cleared session variables, history, etc. No luck.

Comment: Yeah, I just tried it and I'm getting the same error as you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logger is very clear.

```
Requesting url http://127.0.0.1:5000/oauth/token using method POST.
Request to fetch token completed with status 405.
<title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>
<h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>
<p>The method is not allowed for the requested URL.</p>
```

That means you can't POST to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/oauth/token`. If you have ever checked the example at https://github.com/lepture/example-oauth2-server/blob/master/app.py#L223 you will find that it doesn't accept a POST request.

You can either change the example:

```
@app.route('/oauth/token', methods=['POST'])
@oauth.token_handler
def access_token():
    return None
```

Or you can request with a GET method for access token, which I believe can be set in requests-oauthlib.

Comment: Ah, seems pretty obvious now (I'm new to Flask and didn't quite catch that the default there is a GET request). Thank you, Thank you, Thank you!!!!